# Android: Why TextField is not showing?

Tags: java, android, textview, jtextfield

```
    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setX(0);
    t.setY(0);
    t.setText("Tap");
    t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    t.setTextSize(25);
    t.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    setContentView(t);
```

I'am in ActionBarActivity, that why I'am using "this" as context, can't understand why the textField isn't showing, is here something wrong?

Comment: did you add test field?

Comment: Add it in your main layout.

Comment: The code is right and it's worked where do you put this code?

Comment: where did you put it?Do you have some layout which adds your TextView? Do you have something like layout.addChild(t);?

Comment: do you call `setContentView` somewhere else?

Comment: I call setContentView in the oncreate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    TextView t= new TextView(this);
    t.setX(0);
    t.setY(0);
    t.setText("Tap");
    t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    t.setTextSize(25);
    addContentView(t, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
```

Comment: I found it, it was because I had a setContentView that was overriding the previous elements on the screen, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="in.appkart.flashlight.MainActivity" >

</FrameLayout>
```

and MainActivity

```
package in.appkart.flashlight;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_layout);

        TextView t = new TextView(this);

        t.setX(0);
        t.setY(0);
        t.setText("Tap");
        t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        t.setTextSize(25);
        t.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ((FrameLayout) frameLayout).addView(t);
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain for the OP...and You set setContentView twice, that´s not correct...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs It is answer.

Comment: Hey Arun, but posting the code will not have a learn effect, so You should explain, what OP has done wrong and what You have done wright or how it should be done correctly...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs Thank you very much. Sure i will explain answer as well at the time of answering.